# how to put html code in an html email?

Tags: html, email

I have an HTML transactional email that I am sending out.

The email template is coded in HTML.

I would like to include:

```
<a href="blah">blah</a>
```

But have it show up as markup, and not get translated as HTML.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which technology you're using? PHP?

Comment: What language are you sending it with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [HTML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

```
&lt;a href="blah"&gt;blah&lt;/a&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really coding related, it more depends on your email client itself specifically what format it sends out email in; Plain Text, RTF, HTML, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is not for HTML Email only, but for HTML as a Markup Language. As I understand you correctly you want to include the string of text `<a href="blah">blah</a>` in your email and not to be treated as HTML markup.

There is basically one way of doing this

This by using the proper character entity for each single character, you can read more about this here: [HTML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) (see answer by Isaac Truett)

This will result in the following: `&lt;a href=&quot;blah&quot;&gt;blah&lt;/a&gt;`
, there are probably floating loads of generators around on the web.

For extra [semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) is to treat this string as code, by wrapping it inside code tags `<code></code>` resulting in the following: `<code>&lt;a href=&quot;blah&quot;&gt;blah&lt;/a&gt;</code>`.